# Angular llamar a diferentes variables de forma dinámica ¿Es Posible?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola tengo una función para hacer una serie de labores sobre una variable, el tema es que tengo que hacer otra función que es exactamente igual solo cambia la variable sobre la que actúa.

La pregunta es para reutilizar y ahorrar código ¿Podría ser posible mandar el nombre de la variable en un string a la función y que esta utilice la variable correspondiente según el string recibido?

La única forma que yo conozco es poner ambas variables en un array asociativo y pasarle a la función el nombre de la clave asociativa correspondiente del array, pero me parece poco "elegante" crear un array solo para eso y tampoco nunca he hecho algo así en otro lenguaje.

Un ejemplo sencillo de lo que intento hacer:

componente1.component.ts

```
   accionComun (nombreVariable: string) {
    
      //  quiero imprimir la variable que tenga como nombre el string de nombreVariable 
      alert();
    
   }
   
   accionComun("variable1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien la respuesta de [@ivanao](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/419323/188830) es acertada:

> Al final los amigos de StackOverflow en Inglés me dieron una respuesta
> muy buena, solo valida para Angular, eso si.
>
> Resulta que this. funciona como una especie de array:

```
accionComun (nombreVariable: string) {
   
 alert(this[nombreVariable]);
    
}
```

`this` no es una especie de *array* si no un objeto que siempre hace referencia al contexto en el que nos encontremos.

Menciona además que *sólo* es válida para Angular... y eso ***NO es cierto en absoluto***, puesto que cualquier objeto en javascript es accesible mediante la notación de corchetes rectos `[]` además del clásico punto (`obj.x`), tal como demuestra este snippet:

```js
// Ambas veces se mostrará el mismo mensaje!
x = "Hola";
alert(this["x"]);
alert(this.x);
```

En javascript el `this` siempre está disponible, eso si, no siempre hace referencia a lo mismo, si no que el `this` hace referencia al contexto en el que se encuentra actualmente el código, en este caso será el objeto `window`, con lo cual cualquier variable/método declarados estarán disponibles a través del `this` siempre y cuando nos encontremos en el contexto adecuado!

Más información al respeto en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this)

Answer (score 0):

Estaría interesante conocer el caso de uso para lo que comentas, creo que la mejor forma es usar un reductor o un switch case para pasar la referencia a la variable, algo cómo lo siguiente:

```
variableSelector(name: string) {
   switch(name) {
       case 'foo':
         return foo
       case 'bar':
         return bar
   }
}

actionComun(nombre: string) {
  const variable = variableSelector(nombre)
}
```

Comment: No lo veo factible, puesto que cada vez que añadas una variable al código deberás recordar añadirla al `switch` también. Eventualmente se te olvidará, y tendrás un bug   curioso

Answer (score 0):

Al final los amigos de StackOverflow en Inglés me dieron una respuesta muy buena.

Resulta que utilizando corchetes en `this.` se puede acceder a la variable correspondiente:

```
accionComun (nombreVariable: string) {
   
 alert(this[nombreVariable]);
    
}
```

[Enlace pregunta en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426078/angular-to-call-different-variables-dynamically-is-it-possible)